# CardView inside GridLayout going off screen

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I am using a GridLayout with CardViews inside of it to display a set of objects for users to click on and use to navigate around the app.

Everything appears to be fine on my tablet that I am testing on, but when I sent the APK to a friend, 2/3 of it runs off the screen and just doesn't seem to work.

Example screenshot:

[image: preview]

The "Games" section here seems to work just fine. Unable to find any errors, I copy and pasted this section into the "Community" section and just re-named the icons so that the code would be identical except for a few strings.

I don't understand why one section will work and the others do not.

Layout.xml File

````java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    tools:context=".Dashboard">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Dashboard"
                        android:id="@+id/dashTextMain"
                        android:textSize="34sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashTextSub"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/dashTextMain"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                    android:text="Welcome to RoCodes.io,"
                    android:textColor="#E8E8E8"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dashTextSub2"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#E8E8E8"
                    android:text="what would you like to find?"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/dashTextSub"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        //----------------------  START FIRST GRID LAYOUT -------------------------------------

        <TextView
            android:text="Music"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <GridLayout
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            >

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/musicCodesButton"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#FFF"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="16dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_music" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:text="Music Codes"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/artistSearchButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#FFF"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_artist"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="Search Artists"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/categorySearchButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#FFF"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_categories"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="Music Categories"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </GridLayout>
        //----------------------  END FIRST GRID LAYOUT -------------------------------------

        //----------------------  START SECOND GRID LAYOUT -------------------------------------
        <TextView
            android:text="Games"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <GridLayout
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/twitterCodesButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_newcodes"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="New Codes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_gamecodes"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="Coming Soon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>
        //----------------------  END SECOND GRID LAYOUT -------------------------------------

        //----------------------  START THIRD GRID LAYOUT -------------------------------------
        <TextView
            android:text="Community"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <GridLayout
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/discordServerButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_discord"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="RoCodes Discord"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardElevation="6dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/websiteButton"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_website"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="RoCodes Website"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </GridLayout>
        //----------------------  END THIRD GRID LAYOUT -------------------------------------

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>```
````

Comment: I'm suggesting to use recyclerView with different view types, there are a few reasons for using it:
1)items will be recycled when not displayed on a screen which is good for performance
2)easy to maintain item view

Comment: I'll be sure to look into that, but I'm trying to wrap my mind around why this specific code is not working. I'm very new to all of this, so I'd like to learn as much as I can. :)

Comment: Please add a specification of the tablet where the issue was detected

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to align my GridLayout children (especially when using a CardView). I solved it by setting the following attributes for each child:

```
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

Like for example:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grLayout_HelloWorld"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/crdView_simple_Card00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_lime_shade1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_TestCard00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="My First Card" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/crdView_simple_Card01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_lime_shade1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_TestCard01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="My Second Card" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>
```

You will notice that i did not use the `rowWeight` attribute.

**Disclaimer:**

To be honest, I have no idea WHY this works... All I know is that it bothered me for some time, and I spent a lot of time on Google and StackOverflow until I found some info saying that `fill_horizontal` might be the solution... Then I just hacked my way from there, trying different layout attributes until I found `columnWeight` as well.

Hope this helps... Let me know if it works for you.

Good luck, brother (or sister) ✊